# No output on EXCEPT query in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

```
   select 
merchandise.merchname, 
order_item.itemid, 
order_item.orderid
from merchandise Inner join order_item 
on merchandise.MerchName = order_item.itemid
EXCEPT
select 
MerchName,
order_item.itemid, 
order_item.orderid
from merchandise left join order_item 
on merchandise.ItemID = order_item.itemid
```

Need to output those that have not sold.  Not sure what I am doing wrong here. still new to MySQL.

Comment: Does MySQL support EXCEPT now?

Comment: It should I am getting close to outputting it correctly i'm getting error:
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'M82XTi /Marker ' to data type int.


I have a feeling it's my join commands, I deleted group by at the end

Answer (score 1):

Your join looks suspect:

> Inner join order_item 
>   on merchandise.MerchName = order_item.itemid

is `merchandise.MerchName` really have the same type / id as `order_item.itemid`

looking at the rest of the query this should read:

`inner join order_item on merchandise.ItemID = order_item.itemid`

EDIT: [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/except/) added an except clause in version 10.3.0 - but I'm not sure it exists in MySQL so if your actually using MariaDB rather than MySQL you can use an except.

Comment: getting error:
Column 'merchandise.MerchName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @jh86 I'm guessing you solved the GROUP BY error by your comment above, and you now having issues with comparing a text column with an int which looks like your sql is still comparing MerchName with itemid.

Comment: I did remove the GROUP BY command and was able to somewhat  gather the data I needed, but I am not seeing what was not sold and that's what I needed.